# SQL Excercise part 2

Tags: sql

I am stuck on another SQL exercise, here is the question:

Show the 20 biggest cities in the United States along with their rank in the state (with respect to their population) and percent of the city population in a state (call it: perc_pop_state).

Here is what i have so far. This produces the table i am looking for, but for some weird reason the percentages of city population to state population are 0's for all the states with multiple cities and 1 for all states with one city. Can anyone guide me as to what is wrong with my code.

```
select
city.name, city.population, city.district, rank() over (partition by district order by city.population desc), city.population / sum(city.population) over (partition by district) as perc_pop_state
from 
city
inner join country on code = countrycode
where
country.name = 'United States'
order by 
city.population desc
```

[image: ER Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which database this is for, but most likely it's because you the figures are not decimal data type - they are whole numbers, so when you divide them the result is a whole number (0 or 1) rather than a fraction. So you should use something like this

```
CAST(city.population AS DECIMAL(19,4)) 
      / 
CAST(sum(city.population) AS DECIMAL(19,4))
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you have any more questions, please post the type of SQL you are using (SQL Sever, Oracle whatever)